# VS code - search for function reference within specific function- macOS

Tags: redux, visual-studio-code, next.js, redux-devtools

is there any quick way in vs code to search for
method1 referenced inside method2?

I am trying to see if using remote-redux-devtools is useful for my project, and we are using next js which does server side calls via `getInitialProps` so I am trying to find all references to `dispatch` inside `getInitialProps`

rather than search for either term (`dispatch` or `getInitialProps`) via `command + shift + F`  individually, i need a more specific search. 
in this case I need to search for references to `dispatch` inside `getInitialProps`

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that your `getInitialProps` functions are of a form similar to this:

```
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/zeit/next.js')
    const json = await res.json()
    dispatchEvent(event)
    return { stars: json.stargazers_count }
  }
```

particularly with respect to the `return` statement on the final line, then this regex works to distinguish those `getInitialProps` functions with the sequence `dispatch` somewhere in that function.

```
^.*getInitialProps[\s\S]*?\bdispatch[\s\S]*?(return).*\n.*
```

If you want only `dispatch` as opposed to `dispatchEvent` you could use word boundaries around it like `\bdispatch\b` unless it is used as `dispatch(` then use `\bdispatch(` or similar.

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/bLtd2z/1)